# What causes my PHP error in my custom VBO action using a Rules component?

Tags: 7, quiz

I have created a view of unevaluated quiz results and added a vbo field. I created a rule component with action save entity "result" and added the component to the vbo.

When the operation is carried out, it doesn't save the result. But if I add "show message on site", that works.

Enabling debugging, php errors are thrown like so:

> notice: Trying to get property of non object in quiz_access_results() line 186...

I'm using [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) version 7.x-5.1.

Exported Rules Component:

```
{ "rules_save_uncompleted_exams" : {
    "LABEL" : "Save uncompleted exams",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "result" : { "label" : "quiz result", "type" : "quiz_result" } },
    "DO" : [ { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "immediate" : "1" } } ]
  }
}
```

**Note**: Quiz results are saved at first but are not completed "evaluated" until the entire quiz is submitted. So if a user logs out without submitting, the total score will not be evaluated. By creating a vbo, an admin can manually score all the quizes.

Comment: A very basic rule component: Action set -> Action: save entity[result].

Comment: Question updated. Please check

Comment: "show msg on site" works, can you be more specific on that, like what's the msg your rule shows, for each row selected in your VBO view? Also, have you tried "unit testing" the rule without executing it via a VBO action? I.e by using the "execute" link in front of the Rules Component (via the Rules UI). If so can you extend your question to explain how far you get via such "unit testing"? Also, have you tried by using Rules debugging, if so what's the content of the Rules evaluation log?

Comment: What is it (= which functionality) that you really try to achieve with this custom VBO action, implement via this (for now) failing rules component? What I find strange: you have a VBO with results (rows) saved as some type of entities (= quiz results), so these entites **are** saved already (if not they cannot show up as a row). And then your Rules Component needs to save them again (but they are already saved since your VBO view includes them as rows). I'm pretty sure I'm still missing "something", can you help me understand?

Comment: I mentioned that earlier in the question: "Enabling debugging, php errors are thrown "notice: Trying to get property of non object in quiz_access_results() line 186..."

Comment: Quiz results are saved at first but are not completed "evaluated" until the entire quiz is submitted. So if a user logs out without submitting, the total score will not be evaluated. By creating a vbo, an admin can manually score all the quiz

Comment: I'm sorry "that you mentioned that earlier", but I'm only trying to help, OK? I bet that, if you did enable the Rules debugging facilities, your Rules Evaluation log contains other messages (that I'd like to see to better understand what's happening in YOUR scenario. Also, HOW does an admin "manually score such quiz"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58218/discussion-between-primerater01-and-pierre-vriens).